# log4j file not created on my system but showing error on console

Tags: java, xml, swing, log4j, error-log

i am developing a desktop based application on swing, but not able to generate log4j file on client desktop.

My log4j.property file is:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, SECOND_APPENDER
log4j.appender.NotConsole=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.NotConsole.maxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FA.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\log4j-application.log
log4j.logger.com.jd.listing=DEBUG,SECOND_APPENDER
```

My log4j.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration package="log4j.test"
status="WARN">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="log4j.test.Log4jTest" level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Please help me in generating log4j file on my drive.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What error are you seeing? Note that log4j config files are resolved through the classpath, so if there is another one in a jar somewhere that is earlier in the classpath that one will be used instead.

Comment: You may not have permission to write to the clients `c:\` root directory

Comment: @Kenney -- I am not getting any error, my desktop app is worling fine. i just want to get log printed in some file. i put log4j file but not able to find that file on my desktop. When i start my project on eclipse (Luna) then the error get printed in console. I want these error to b printed in a file(like word, txt etc.).

Comment: @MadProgrammer-- i have changed that path to D:\\getLog.log. but not able to get the logs

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I've replaced the SECOND_APPENDER with stdout and added the stdout

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, R
log4j.appender.NotConsole=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.NotConsole.maxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FA.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\log4j-application.log
log4j.logger.com.jd.listing=DEBUG

# Standard output logging
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}[%x]::[%t]:(%l:%L):%-5p:%c{1}:%m%n

# Rolling file logging
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=mylogfile.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MMM:dd:HH:mm:ss,SSS}:[%t]:(%C{1}.%M:%L):%-5p:%c{1}:%m%n
```

The log4j.xml is not required.

Comment: i made the changes that you suggested to me, but still i am not able to generate the log file

Comment: I've added a seconder appender to the property file.  That will log the output to a file named "mylogfile.log".  You now should be able to see the output on the console and also the logfile.